# RegEx to return 'href' attribute of 'link' tags only?

Tags: html, regex, href

Im trying to craft a regex that only returns `<link>` tag hrefs

Why does this regex return all hrefs including <a hrefs?

```
(?&lt;=&lt;link\s+.*?)href\s*=\s*[\'\"][^\'\"]+
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" rev="stylesheet" href="idlecore-tidied.css?T_2_5_0_228" media="screen">
<a href="anotherurl">Slash Boxes&lt;/a>
```

Comment: Please rephrase the question. I don't think anyone will understand your question as it stands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either

```
/(?<=<link\b[^<>]*?)\bhref=\s*=\s*(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']'|\S+)/
```

or

```
/<link\b[^<>]*?\b(href=\s*=\s*(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']'|\S+))/
```

The main difference is `[^<>]*?` instead of `.*?`. This is because you don't want it to continue the search into other tags.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid lookbehind for such simple case, just match what you need, and capture what you want to get.

I got good results with `<link\s+[^>]*(href\s*=\s*(['"]).*?\2)` in The Regex Coach with s and g options.

Answer (score 0):

```
/(?<=<link\s+.*?)href\s*=\s*[\'\"][^\'\"]+[^>]*>/
```

i'm a little shaky on the back-references myself, so I left that in there. This regex though:

```
/(<link\s+.*?)href\s*=\s*[\'\"][^\'\"]+[^>]*>/
```

...works in my Javascript test.

Answer (score 0):

What regex flavor are you using? Perl, for one, doesn't support variable-length lookbehind. Where that's an option, I'd choose (edited to implement the very good idea from MizardX):

```
(?<=<link\b[^<>]*?)href\s*=\s*(['"])(?:(?!\1).)+\1
```

as a first approximation. That way the choice of quote character (' or ") will be matched.
The same for a language without support for (variable-length) lookbehind:

```
(?:<link\b[^<>]*?)(href\s*=\s*(['"])(?:(?!\2).)+\2)
```

\1 will contain your match.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=<link\s+.*?)href\s*=\s*[\'\"][^\'\"]+
```

works with [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) (I think Expresso runs on the .NET regex-engine). You could even refine this a bit more to match the closing `'` or 
`"`:

```
(?<=<link\s+.*?)href\s*=\s*([\'\"])[^\'\"]+(\1)
```

Perhaps your regex-engine doesn't work with lookbehind assertions. A workaround would be

```
(?:<link\s+.*?)(href\s*=\s*([\'\"])[^\'\"]+(\2))
```

Your match will then be in the captured group 1.