# Getting all links from a webpage

Tags: java, regex, url, hyperlink

I would like to get all links in a page after doing a GET , my code works for some websites but not for others while debugging it showed that no matches were found and it never enters inside the while loop, although there are links in that website

```
  Pattern linkPattern = Pattern.compile("<a[^>]+href=[\"']?([\"'>]+)[\"']?[^>]*>(.+?)",               
    Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher pageMatcher = linkPattern.matcher(Content);

    if (FindKeyword(Content)) {
        LinksWithKey.add(HostName);
    }
        count++;

    while (pageMatcher.find()) {
```

Comment: Show an example or URL not matched by our regexp

Comment: Jsoup would be easier?

Comment: You may want to take a look at [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/). They even have an [example](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links) showing how to extract links from a downloaded page.

Comment: Don't try to use a RegEx where you need a parser.  This needs a parser.

Comment: @Perception .. it is required to use sockets therefore, I think I need to search for them

Comment: *"it is required to use sockets therefore, I think I need to search for them"*  Did that make sense in your head?  Hear it reads like nonsense.

Comment: @HayaRaed - retrieving the data and parsing it are two ***entirely*** different things. Aka, being required to use sockets to retrieve the data says nothing about any requirements you may have been given on how to parse it. Is this homework?

Comment: @Perception you already have the HTML in that `Content` variable. So you can use JSOUP.

Comment: @Alex - I am not entirely (at all) sure what you are referring too.

Comment: @Alex yes Content has the HTML file, I will try to use Jsoup

Comment: @Perception thank you for the clarification and I apologize if my comment was confusing and Yes it is an assignment, the course is open notes and open internet .. we don't take everything in class , we need to research and discover things on our own

Comment: @HayaRaed - thanks for clarifying. If you are allowed to use third party libraries then definitely consider using Jsoup for the parsing task, it will make your life much easier. Otherwise, see [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268338/regex-to-return-href-attribute-of-link-tags-only) for a possible set of regexes you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Like all said in the comments, you should consider using [JSoup](http://jsoup.org) for such a task.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(Content); // this is your original HTML content
for (Element link : doc.select("a[href]")) {
    System.out.println(link.attr("href"));
}
```

Comment: I have tried using JSOUP but the loop is only entered once and not more even if there are other links